# Set PATH for /bin/sh in Debian:11 image

Tags: shell, docker, environment-variables

**Background**

I am building an image based on Debian:11. I am trying to set the `PATH` for the `/bin/sh` with a dynamic value determined *at image build-time*. (The "*at image build time*" is important. I cannot simply include a static `ENV PATH` in my Dockerfile.)

**The Problem**

When I run:

```
docker build . --tag debian-with-chrome-driver
docker run -it --rm debian-with-chrome-driver
echo $PATH
```

The actual result is:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

The desired result is:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/chromedriver/linux-119.0.6045.105/chromedriver-linux64
```

**What I have tried**

Based on a variety of StackExchange posts, I have tried setting the `PATH` in the following:

- `/etc/profile`
- `/etc/login.defs`
- `/etc/environment`

The following shows the relevant contents of the above files:

```
# tail -n 3 /etc/profile
PATH=${PATH}:/chromedriver/linux-119.0.6045.105/chromedriver-linux64
export PATH

# cat /etc/login.defs | grep chromedriver
ENV_SUPATH      PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/chromedriver/linux-119.0.6045.105/chromedriver-linux64
ENV_PATH        PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/chromedriver/linux-119.0.6045.105/chromedriver-linux64

# cat /etc/environment
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/chromedriver/linux-119.0.6045.105/chromedriver-linux64
```

I have successfully set the path for bash (as shown in the following.) But I need to set the path for the sh.

```
# bash  
root@4e159cfc9fe5:/# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/chromedriver/linux-119.0.6045.105/chromedriver-linux64
```

**Dockerfile**

You can try it yourself:

```
docker build . --tag debian-with-chrome-driver
```

```
FROM debian:11

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl

# from https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#deb
RUN curl -SLO https://deb.nodesource.com/nsolid_setup_deb.sh \
    && chmod 500 nsolid_setup_deb.sh \
    && ./nsolid_setup_deb.sh 21 \
    && apt-get -y install nodejs

# from https://developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-for-testing/#how-can-i-get-chrome-for-testing-binaries
RUN npx -y @puppeteer/browsers install chrome@stable \
    && npx -y @puppeteer/browsers install chromedriver@stable

# add the chromedriver to the PATH
RUN export CHROME_DRIVER_PATH=$(find /chromedriver -name "chromedriver" -type f -executable -printf "%h" -quit) \
    && export APPEND_CHROME_DRIVER_PATH="PATH="'${PATH}'":${CHROME_DRIVER_PATH}" \
    # \
    && echo "export ${APPEND_CHROME_DRIVER_PATH}\n" >> /etc/bash.bashrc \
    && echo "${APPEND_CHROME_DRIVER_PATH}\nexport PATH\n" >> /etc/profile \
    # \
    && export CHROME_DRIVER_PATH_ESCAPED=$(echo ${CHROME_DRIVER_PATH} | sed 's/\//\\\//g') \
    && sed -i '/^ENV_SUPATH.*/ s/$/:'"${CHROME_DRIVER_PATH_ESCAPED}"'/' /etc/login.defs \
    && sed -i '/^ENV_PATH.*/ s/$/:'"${CHROME_DRIVER_PATH_ESCAPED}"'/' /etc/login.defs \
    # \
    && echo "PATH=${PATH}:${CHROME_DRIVER_PATH}\n" >> /etc/environment \
    && echo ${PATH}

ENTRYPOINT [ "bin/sh" ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `/bin/sh` in Debian (`dash`), `/etc/profile` and so on are only used for login shells. For non-login shells, you can specify a startup script to use in the `ENV` environment variable. At the end of your `Dockerfile`:

```
    && echo "PATH=${PATH}:${CHROME_DRIVER_PATH}\n" >> /etc/environment \
    && echo "PATH=${PATH}:${CHROME_DRIVER_PATH}\n" >> /etc/shinit \
    && chmod 755 /etc/shinit \
    && echo ${PATH}

ENV ENV=/etc/shinit

ENTRYPOINT [ "bin/sh" ]
```